# unable to get a response from the express nodejs server when being directed to a html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

When clicking the buttons in my public/index.html I am being directed to game.html but it doesn't show any response. It says `This site can’t provide a secure connection: localhost sent an invalid response.` The index.html page is loaded when I go to localhost:3000 and after clicking on the buttons I am being directed to game.html but the server doesn't load the page.

### public/index.html

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<button class="w3-button w3-hover-black"> </button>

<!-- JavaScript -->   
<script>
  var buttons=  document.getElementsByClassName('w3-button w3-hover-black');
  for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/game.html";
   }
 }
</script>
```

### public/game.html

```html
 <div id = "gameDiv"></div>
 <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src = "lib/phaser.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "main.js"></script>
 <script src = "player.js"></script>
```

### server/server.js

```js
var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT ||3000 ;
const pathjoin = path.join(__dirname, '../public'); 
const pathjoin1 = path.join(__dirname,'../public/game.html');
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(pathjoin));

app.get('/game.html',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(pathjoin1);
});

var io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  console.log('user connected ' + socket.id);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking to download the html file when you go to /game, or do you want to render it as html?

Comment: render it as  html

Answer (score 1):

What you want is res.render: [some docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render)

An example:

```
const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.get('/game.html',(req, res) => {
  res.render('game.html');
});
```

Comment: but can you please tell me why the difference between res.render and res.sendFile and why did we use res.render and not res.sendFile?

Comment: sendFile `Transfers the file at the given path`, were as render `Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client`. In other words when you use sendFile it tries to download the file instead of display it in the browser window. here are the references to those quotes: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile & https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render

Comment: yeah. .i googled it in the 6 mins between your reply and my question!:) thanks a lot Rick! btw why dont we specify the file path inside the res.render() unlike app.use()? how does the server comes to know about the file game.html/